# What is the best way to show custom message loader when sequence of AJAX calls are executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When set of JQuery AJAX calls are executing synchronously I would like to show a message which AJAX call is curring executing, so that user can wait till all the calls executed.

What I tried is using the JQuery,

```
LoadAllData();

function LoadAllData()
{
  $('#spMsg').text('Wait, fetching data1...); 
  ajaxCallForData1();

  $('#spMsg').text('Wait, fetching data2...); 
  ajaxCallForData2();

  $('#spMsg').text('Wait, fetching data3...); 
  ajaxCallForData3();
}
```

But the issue is **$('#spMsg')** is not updating unless all the AJAX calls are executed.

I have tried the JQuery Block UI plug in, but works good for single ajax call but not for sequence of calls in a function. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Embrace the asynchronous nature of asynchronous calls.

Comment: I think you should take a look a promises and how to chain them, they exactly fit your needs once you get to know how to deal with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)